# Different print dimensions from different printers by same C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

The same C# application is printing text in different dimension by different printers. The text printed is same along x-axis but differ along y-axis. I mean in one print, the text is slightly(4-5mm) upwards than other print but same along x-axis i.e. no text is backwards or forward than text of other print. Eg:

"This text is same along x-axis but differ among y-axis"(Print 1)
"This text is same along x-axis but differ among y-axis"(Print 2)

My Page settings are:

```
private void PaperSettings()
{
    PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("New Page", 377, 1095);
    paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
    Margins margin = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margin;
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer.PrinterName;
}
```

On changing the paper width(377) manually, the text is shifted upwards on increasing it and downwards on decreasing it. However the same page settings is not working on different printers***(HP Officejet J3500 printing text slightly downdards than text printed by HP Deskjet 1510).***

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{            
    e.Graphics.DrawString(label1Payee.Text, label1Payee.Font, Brushes.Black, label1Payee.Location.X, label1Payee.Location.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(labelAmountWords.Text, labelAmountWords.Font, Brushes.Black, labelAmountWords.Location.X, labelAmountWords.Location.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(labelDate1.Text, labelDate1.Font, Brushes.Black, labelDate1.Location.X, labelDate1.Location.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(labelAmount.Text, labelAmount.Font, Brushes.Black, labelAmount.Location.X, labelAmount.Location.Y);            
}
```

Any Suggestions..
Thank you!

Comment: The origin will differ between hardware/drivers. I did a "precise printing" project a while ago and I ended up forcing users to print a calibration page (print an X at (0,0)), enter the offset from the top-left of the page in mm and calculate a printer specific offset that I then transformed the print coordinates with.

Comment: @AlexK. Ohhh.. Please help me out on how to achieve this by providing some more details and some basic code.

Answer (score 0):

Every printer has some margins where the printer does not print. These margins are called printer's `HardMargins`. Say you want to print something on co-ordinates `(0, 0)` but my printer prints it on `(16, 16)`. This `(HardMarginX, HardMarginY)`.

Every printer may differ from hard margins. e.g. My HP LaserJet 1020 is `(16, 16)` but my Canon Pixma ip1300 is `(0, 0)`.

So what you have to do is, get the `HardMarginX` and `HardMarginY`, do some math and print where you want to print.

One more thing, if you try to print beyond these margins, document may be clipped. Search for the `PrintableArea` of the printer over internet and you get the idea.